# SASS - Applying changer to ::after when :hover

Tags: css, sass, pseudo-element

I'm trying to apply changes on the ::after element when :hover but it doesn't work, here's my code and please tell me what's wrong, thank you!

```css
&::after
  content: ""
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  background:
    image: url('../img/couverture.jpg')
    size: cover
    position: center
    repeat: no-repeat
  //outline: 1px solid red
  position: absolute
  z-index: 1
  &::after:hover
    outline: 1px solid red
```

Comment: post your full code

Comment: What about `&:hover` in the same indentation of `&::after`

Comment: Is the second `::after` intended to be nested within the first? That is how you code currently reads. Adding curly braces would make things more clear.

Comment: `::after` doesn't seem to be hoverable; something simple like a plain CSS  `div::after:hover {
  color:red;
}` doesn't work in any browser. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/2vqhekc8/). Unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: If someone could find a word-of-God page (W3C, WHATWG, browser makers...) about whether you can hover a pseudo element or not, that would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indent the hover within the after like the below:

```
.element {
    &:after {
        &:hover {
            styling:here;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
:after:hover
```

try

```
:hover:after
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your rendered CSS will be like,

`Element::after::after:hover{
    outline: 1px solid red
}`

Which is invalid, Also `hover` on `:after` will not work.